# Android HttpPost Error only after a Change in the Connecting Web Server

Tags: android, http-post

A very Peculiar issue with HttpPost from an Android App ! Hope some one can help..

The App connects to a URL (PHP ~ MySQL) in a remote server and fetch JSON for the application to display. It works fine, till the time you run a PHP Page in the same remote server to update the MySQL Database using a Form Post and Insert Method.

After the update, for a minute, the Android App can not connect to the Remote Server and throws httphostconnectexception: Connection Refused to the Server (The URL) error. After a Minute everything will start working normally.

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection refused means that nothing was listening on the port at the server side. If you did updates to the server, it can be unavailable for a while when it is restarting. Nothing to do with Android, BTW.